# Display value in dropdown based on first dropdown

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a working form here which populating dropdown from the database, i want to do here is display the value of 2nd dropdown based on the selected value on the 1st dropdown, but how i'm gonna do it.  My Class will only display on the 2nd drowpdown if error is selected which the 1st dropdown

//my screenshot, my only sample data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxQDq.png)

Backend code:

```
        public JsonResult GetErrorCategory()
        {

            List<ErrorCategory> error = errorDataAccessLayer.GetAllError(Action);
            return Json(error.Select(x => new
            {

                errorCode = x.ErrorCode,
                errorDescription = x.ErrorDescription
            }).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public JsonResult GetClassCategory()
        {

            List<ErrorClass> error = errorDataAccessLayer.GetAllClass(Action);
            return Json(error.Select(x => new
            {

                classCode = x.ClassCode,
               classDescription = x.ClassDescription
            }).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

View:

```
    <form id="ticket_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
           <label><strong>Error Type</strong></label>
           <select name="ErrorType" id="ErrorDropdown" class="form-control ErrorType" >
      </select>
         </div>              
         </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="form-group col-md-4">
       <label><strong>Class Type</strong></label>
     <select name="ClassType" id="ClassDropdown" class="form-control ClassType" >
       </select>
         </div>
          </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" id="addTicket" value="Create" class="btn btn-md btn-outline-secondary" style="margin:auto;display:block;" />
             </div>
          </form>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Ticket/GetErrorCategory",
                data: "{}",
                success: function (data) {

                    var s = 'option value="-1">Please Select Error Type</option>';

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                        s += '<option value="' + data[i].errorDescription + '">' + data[i].errorDescription + '</option>';

                    }
                    s += '<option value="Others">Others</option>';
                    $("#ErrorDropdown").html(s);

                }

            });



                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Ticket/GetClassCategory",
                    data: "{}",
                    success: function (data) {

                        var s = 'option value="-1">Please Select Class Type</option>';

                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                            s += '<option value="' + data[i].classDescription + '">' + data[i].classDescription + '</option>';

                        }
                        s += '<option value="Others">Others</option>';
                        $("#ClassDropdown").html(s);

                    }

                });
 });

</script>
```

Comment: Yo must handle onchange() event of first dropdown, and then pass selected item value to the second method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in script section you need split functions like as following. You see I added `code parameter` to the second `GetClassCategory` method:

```
function GetErrorCategory() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Ticket/GetErrorCategory",
        data: "{}",
        success: function (data) {
            var s = 'option value="-1">Please Select Error Type</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                s += '<option value="' + data[i].errorDescription + '">' + data[i].errorDescription + '</option>';
            }
            s += '<option value="Others">Others</option>';
            $("#ErrorDropdown").html(s);

            // This line applies onchange event for errorcategory dropdown
            ApplyErrorCategoryDropDownOnChange();
        }
    }
}

function GetClassCategory(code) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Ticket/GetClassCategory",
        data: JSON.stringify({ code: code }),
        success: function (data) {
            var s = 'option value="-1">Please Select Class Type</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                s += '<option value="' + data[i].classDescription + '">' + data[i].classDescription + '</option>';
            }
            s += '<option value="Others">Others</option>';
            $("#ClassDropdown").html(s);
        }
    });
}
```

Second, you need handle `onchange()` event, because when another item of the first dropwdown selected then you need get it's value.

```
function ApplyErrorCategoryDropDownOnChange() {
    $("#ErrorDropdown").change(function (data) {
        GetClassCategory(this.value)
    });
}
```

Third, you must call `GetErrorCategory()` method from document ready function.

```
$(function () {
    GetErrorCategory();
});
```

Fourth, you need add code parameter in the backend section, and apply this parameter to your db query:

```
public JsonResult GetClassCategory(string code) // I added parameter
{
    List < ErrorClass > error = errorDataAccessLayer.GetAllClass(Action);
    return Json(
        error
            .Where(x => x.ClassCode = code) // I added this section
            .Select(x => new
                {

                    classCode = x.ClassCode,
                    classDescription = x.ClassDescription
                }).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: hi , i highly appreciated your effort, but the 2nd dropdown. doesnt change anything, and for the ApplyErrorCategoryDropDownOnChange() , data is not highlighted

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your code in your second ajax call, i mean it should be some dependent conditional to the first dropdown, For that you just need to get the value of the first dropdown to the second dropdown ajax call while it is selected. Just i mention below :

```
var error=document.getElementById("ErrorDropdown").value;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Ticket/GetClassCategory",
                data: "{error:error}",
                success: function (data) {

                    var s = 'option value="-1">Please Select Class Type</option>';

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                        s += '<option value="' + data[i].classDescription + '">' + data[i].classDescription + '</option>';

                    }
                    s += '<option value="Others">Others</option>';
                    $("#ClassDropdown").html(s);

                }

            });
```

Here i have the value of the first dropdown in variable named as error and i have passed it through the ajax call and use it in my database query with where clause.

Comment: do i need some onchange() ?

Comment: Yes you do, because onchange() is the only way when we get the exact error from the first dropdown change. And after that your second ajax is called in the same onchange().